# Expose two ports, one as ClusterIP and other as NodePort

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod with two containers. An application and a database. I have two replicas for the pod.

I want to expose the application port to be accessed outside the cluster and I do not want to expose the database port.

But I want to access the database port using DNS to balance the traffic.

I can create two services one as NodePort and expose the applicatin port and other service as ClusterIP to expose the database port.

I could also connect to localhost from the application server as the traffic has been balance before. And only expose the app server as nodeport.

The questions is: Could I expose the database port as cluster ip and the app port as nodeport with only one service?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't.

Not to mention the fact it is a really rare situation where it makes sense to keep database in the same pod in a replicated setup, as you usually want to separate them into different deployments/services.

Comment: If the database is only for the application running in the pod why is it rare? I would say that is the microservice approach. Simple isolated applications.

Comment: For starters, you replicate microservices. Unless your db does some serious replication magic (or your services do not share state) you will be in trouble as soon as you start running multiple instances. Also, it's preferable to be able to scale state store (db) and service each separately. If your svc does something reasonable often it might be that you need to add pods that *do* stuff, but not the ones that store state. Another thing is data persistance - how do you retain data over pods being destroyed (unless you dont need persistency). There is more to it, but char limit kicks in... :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: No, you can not.

But you should still know that a Kubernetes Service of type `NodePort` will also allocate a Cluster IP to which the port will route. So if your wanted to publish both ports, a single Service would be sufficient to reach them internally via the name and externally via node ports.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that both ports will be exposed as NodePort. I want only one as NodePort and the other only internal. I also thought that as Nodeport is over a ClusterIP I could access the ddbb port, but if I do not specify it in the service description it is not exposed neither as ClusterIP nor NodePort.

Comment: Yes, this is why the actual answer is "no".